# Scroll does not work when parent div overflow is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have problem with setting scroll with one specific div. I need to say that i have set `overflow:hidden` to `body` tag.

There are two controls (`asp:Table` and `asp:Panel`) within `<div class='scrollable'>`. `asp:Table` is scrollable even if body overflow is hidden, but `asp:Panel` is not (did the same thing as in `asp:Table`).

Here's code:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <asp:Table ID="TasksTable" runat="server" CssClass="container">

            THERE ARE SIMPLE TABLE TAGS without any mention to overflow

            </asp:Table>
            <asp:Panel ID="TaskDetail" CssClass="taskDetail" runat="server">
                  <div class='detailDiv'>
                      There are <hX> and <p> tags, nothing special
                  </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #e8b03a;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 99%;
}

.container tr {
    text-align: center;

}

.container th {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #73697f;
    border: 1px white;
}
.taskDetail {
    /* display: none; */
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I have problem with making `TasksDetails` scrollable. For example, there are 30 table rows in `TasksTable`. Every one has `click` function, that makes other rows hidden and **it makes `scrollable` non-scrollable** (its toggling class `noScroll { overflow:hidden; }`).

It's something like table row details: I click on table row, `.taskDetail` appears (default there is `display:none`) below selected table row.

How to make `.taskDetail` or `detailDiv` scrollable ?

Answer (score 0):

Just `addClass()` .scrollable to the div or apply next css() method

```
$(".taskDetail").css("overflow-y", "scroll")
```

```js
$(".detailDiv").addClass("scrollable")
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #e8b03a;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 99%;
}

.container tr {
    text-align: center;

}

.container th {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #73697f;
    border: 1px white;
}
.taskDetail {
    /* display: none; */
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <asp:Table ID="TasksTable" runat="server" CssClass="container">

            THERE ARE SIMPLE TABLE TAGS without any mention to overflow

            </asp:Table>
            <asp:Panel ID="TaskDetail" CssClass="taskDetail" runat="server">
                  <div class='detailDiv'>
                      There are and <p> tags, nothing special
                  </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `taskDetail` is still non-scrollable

Comment: No it didn't work. Is it possible that `position` properties of parent divs makes that `taskDetail` cant be scrollable ?

Comment: You can change css properties with css() in each tag you need it

Comment: add about 100 <p> tags within `detailDiv` and you will see it does not work